# can I undo $rvm gemset use global?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, undo, gemset

I cannot get into my rails console anymore after issuing this in my (OSX) terminal:

```
$gem install pry pry-doc
$rvm gemset use global
$gem install pry pry-doc
```

I was following along with http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails?view=asciicast
the pry tutorial of RailsCasts.

my actual error is this when typing $rails console:

```
rails console
/Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 15 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

but in all honesty, since everything seemed to work fine (with the exception of pry in this particular project)  I would really like to just completely UNDO this command. Is that possible??

after those three commands, things seem broken in multiple projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type

```
$ rvm gemset list
```

to see all your gemsets, then type:

```
$rvm gemset use <insert gemset name here>
```

You must have just switched to a different gemset that doesn't have the required gems. You might need to do a $bundle install